# Live charts in Excel: for future dates, lines drop to zero

Tags: excel, charts, worksheet-function

I run live market charts in Excel. A graph indicator runs from live data fed by the broker through the DDE facility in Microsoft Excel. It works fine and I am happy with it - except for one blemish I hope you can assist with.

The lines of the graph (it is a line chart type) are created in real time. The present time and the past time are great, very clean. Unfortunately in the period just ahead i.e. that hasn't arrived yet, the lines of the graph drop to zero and crawl along the x-axis into the future. This spoils the current reading of the graph.

Is there any way I can prevent this happening so that the lines (properly called curves) only exist in the past and current time period. The worksheet is set not to show zero values in formulae, but the charting facility does not appear to have this function.

Answer (score 2):

If you put `#N/A` in the cell (using the `=NA()` function) the points are not drawn.

To hide the ugliness of your cells now having #N/A in them for future dates you can use a number format or conditional formatting to hide error values.  You do this by adding a formula to your conditional formatting of

```
=ISNA(A1)
```

and setting the format to be a white font on a white background.  Which makes the cells with #N/A in them appear blank.  For versions of Excel prior to conditional formatting being available you can do the same thing with a number format but in reverse.  i.e., set your font to white so all cells are invisible by default and set your number format to:

```
[black]0.0;[red]-0.0;[black]0.0;[black]
```

which should make anything that isn't an error appear with either a black or red font colour.
Regards

Dave

Comment: Thanks but not sure where to incorporate. Tried nesting this function in the cell's IF function as follows: =NA()*IF(B93<>"",(I93+N93+S93)/3,"") but no luck.

Comment: Hi Tony, nearly right, should be: =IF(B93<>"",(I93+N93+S93)/3,NA())

Comment: ...and when you get it working, please remember to accept the answer ;o)

Answer (score 1):

I once saved an Excel 97 Worksheet (with charts) in Excel 2003.  After that, whenever I saved the file in '97, I got a prompt telling me that the spreadsheet was created in a newer version of Excel.

To eliminate the prompt I opened it in 2003 and saved it as an Excel 5.0/95 Workbook (*.xls). Then whenever I opened it in 97 the line charts dropped to zero at the end. They didn't do that before.

To correct the problem I right-clicked on the chart, selected Chart type, selected Custom Types, then "Colored Lines". Apparently when I saved it as Excel 5.0/95 that chart type was not supported, so the program defaulted to the type "Smooth Lines". After changing the chart type to "Colored Lines" it was only necessary to do some minor formatting.

This experience suggests a solution to the line dropping to zero problem regardless of what triggered it. Simply change the chart type. When I did that the dropped line disappeared and I didn't have to use the #N/A approach.